# Navigate location history backwards step by step in Emacs

Tags: emacs, navigation, location, buffer, history

*This is **not** a question about how to use mark ring with C-u C-space.*

What I want is to navigate location history backwards step by step. By "step" I mean any single **atomic** cursor move in a buffer. For example, cursor is in the middle of the line and I issue C-f 3 times to move it forward 3 characters and then C-e to jump at the line's end. Now I want to go back by "undoing" C-e first and then 3 previous C-f. So, I press some key and it brings cursor to the place where C-e was issued, then one character back, and so on. It's like pushing mark on every cursor move in the buffer and then using C-u C-space, but automatically and less noisy.

How to do it in Emacs?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Emacs does not record those movements anywhere, so in order to do what you want, you'll need to record buffer positions.  Something like

```
(defvar my-positions-history nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-positions-history)
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-record-positions)
(defun my-record-positions ()
  (unless (and my-positions-history
               (equal (point) (marker-position (car my-positions-history))))
    (push (point-marker) my-positions-history)))
```

Note that this will create a large number of markers, which can significantly slow down Emacs.  Using `(point)` instead of `(point-marker)` would solve this issue but then those positions would not keep track of modifications to the buffer, so they might not bring you back to where you were if the buffer was modified since you performed this motion.

Then you can add a command like

```
(defun my-undo-movement ()
  (interactive)
  (while (and my-positions-history
               (equal (point) (marker-position (car my-positions-history))))
    (pop my-positions-history))
  (when my-positions-history
    (goto-char (pop my-positions-history))))
```

Comment: Can't get it working: it says 'void variable my-record-positions' when evaluating add-hook. I tried to make it buffer local and add-hook worked but seems it's never called and my-positions-history is always nil. Emacs 24.1.

Answer (score 3):

There are several alternatives on EmacsWiki: [quick-jump](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/quick-jump.el), [point-undo](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/point-undo.el), [jump-to-prev-pos](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JumpToPrevPos), [goto-last-point](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/goto-last-point.el)

Comment: I added goto-last-point, a module I just wrote before someone linked me to this page and the various similar but-not-quite-the-same implementations.